# Jasmine + Angular module constants

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have one Angular application,where I have defined constants for application.

```
var module=angular.module('abc');
module.constant('constants',{
  INTERNAL_VALUE:1
});
```

in my controller I have written below lines

```
  if(someService.getInternalValue() === constants.INTERNAL_VALUE){
        $scope.showDropdown=true;
        someservice.somefunction().then(function(data){
          $scope.dropDownData=data;
        });
     }else{
         $scope.showDropdown=false;
     }
```

I have written jasmine test case for if condition but it always went to else condition.

```
it('should show dropdown on user persmission',inject(function($controller){
                spyOn(someServiceMock,'getInternalValue').andCallFake(function(){
                    return 1;
                });
                expect(someServiceMock.getInternalValue()).toBe(1); // passed 
                expect(constants.INTERNAL_VALUE).toBe(1);// passed
                expect(scope.showDropdown).toBe(true); // here it should be true but I am getting "Expected false to be true." error                    
            }));
```

When I have done some RnD then I came to know that it's happening because of constants. I think constants are not injected properly

Can anyone had faced this issue?
Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Please post your full jasmine test too.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings: Changed the post as per your suggestion

Comment: Try to put `spyOn` line outside of `it()` block in `beforeEach` if you have it.

Comment: @Engineer I have does the change and put spyOn before controller declaration and its working.

But I want to test two scenarios one is positive and negative. If above mock method return 1 then it's positive scenario and it will call mock service. and 1st scenario has been tested.

Now I want to test the scenario if mock method return 2 then it should not call service.So,what should be the approach for the same?

Comment: @JayPatel In my answer, I explained, that you need to place `spyOn` call before the spied method will be called. That is the main clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your `spyOn` method is get called after the controller's `if` statement would be executed. So you need to put `spyOn` call before that execution. Move the `spyOn` execution from `it` block to `beforeEach` block.

Comment: How to use SpyOn() multiple time on same function which only returns int values? I had tried with andCallFake but it's not working.1st time it executed properly but 2nd time,It gives me error like the method is already spied upon.

Comment: You can use `.reset` on spied function -> `someServiceMock.getInternalValue.reset()` before creating new spy. However, I am sure , you can structure your tests in such way, that there will be no need of resetting.